Как расширить пространство для Linux за счёт Windows
Я установил Linux Debian рядом с Windows 11 и выделил под него 40 гб. Могу ли я теперь расширить диск Linux если сожму том в Windows?

Да. Загрузитесь с любой флешки в режиме LiveUSB(LinuxMint например)  и воспользуйтесь GParted
